# Dynamic memory allocation grayed out in simulink

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, simulink

I have a simulink model in which I need to use dynamic memory allocation ro run the model.
For some reason, in the config. dialog box the "dynamic memory allocation for MATLAB functions" is grayed out and I cannot enable it.
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? If you right click on the parameter and choose "What is this?" and then "show more information" it opens an info page with dependencies related to this parameter.

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2019b.